# Particle physics bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographystyle

So, I noticed that many particle physics articles in the arXiv use a certain bibliography style that I like very much. An example can be found for instance in https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.08127. However, as yet I have been unable to figure out which is the particular style they are using, and I would really like to use it myself, so would anyone be able to identify it? Thanks in advance.

For your convenience, here is an image from the article I refer to:
[image]

Comment: As the paper is on arXiv, you can download the source: it tells us they use `utphys`.

Comment: You are so right, thank you! I always forget about that feature